# HTML, Auto neutralizes php tag

Tags: php, html

I try to understand why html is automatically do the following action:

This is some code example:

```
<?
$obj = ['name' => 'someValue', 'age' => 55];
```

will result in:

```
<!--?
$obj = ['name' =--> 'someValue', 'age' => 55];
```

**The file is .htm**, So i found that the `<?` and `>` is converted to opening and closing html comment tags `<!--` and `-->`.

I notice that the main problem is with the `?`, If i remove the `?` there will be no problem, If anyone know why the escape is done, Is there a reason for `<?` and `>` to be escaped?, Is it only `<?` and `>` that active this action?, I really lost here if anyone can help i will be very thankful.

**Edit:**

1. I'm using **chrome**
2. The problem is happen locally(file://) and via domain.
3. I'm using apache and .htm files don't parse by the php engine.
4. I do not want to parse the file as php file.

Comment: Why is your PHP file having an extension `.htm` at first place

Comment: You did not specify if you open it from a webserver or locally, whether the file is interpreted or not, or which browser you use that parses it that way. How is anyone supposed to help you?

Comment: what software are you working with? a CMS that can edit files?

Comment: And you did not specify what you are trying to achieve, that can't be solved by changing the extension to `.php` and the code to `<?php`.

Comment: Anyway, I tested a bit and the browsers (Gecko and Blink both) do change the flawed html to a comment. And indeed, they don't do that if you remove the question mark. So your observation is correct, but it doesn't have any real consequences. Just the browsers' way of coping with crud.

Comment: Hey @MrLister Thank you for you comment, Can you give me a link to your sources where you read it, If you answer the question i will approve your answer.

Comment: Where I read what? I tested myself, here on my own computer, with your source. Anyway, what are you trying to accomplish? As was mentioned, a file ending in `.htm` is not a PHP file, so there's no PHP that can be run.

Comment: Is there a source where you can process code vs multiple browsers or you just tested vs multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes, I do have all the mayor browsers on my computer; some native and some in virtual machines running different operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, the sequence `<?` begins a "processing instruction", with a name, optional attributes, and a closing `?>`. For instance, `<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>` applies a CSS stylesheet to an XML document. PHP's standard opening tag (`<?php`) is technically a valid PI (though not really used as such), but the "short tag" `<?` is not.

Although HTML is not, in most cases, XML, there are common features, so browsers may be interpreting your `<?` in that light. On the other hand, they might simply be seeing it as an HTML tag, since anything beginning with `<` should be, but `<?` is not a valid tag. Note that the comment has been set to end at the next occurence of `>`, since that is what would normally end a tag.

The comment-markers in the source are the browser's reinterpretation of what is, either way, invalid markup - since it is inside an invalid tag, it should not show up in the output, so treating it as a comment is equivalent to deleting it from the rendered representation.

If your intention is to display the source of the PHP file, you will need to first HTML escape it, so that the `<?` becomes `&lt;?`; this will cause it to display as `<?` on the screen, rather than being interpreted as (broken) HTML.

Comment: Thank you IMSoP, I think i understand it now.